# What is the naming convention for tables that keep track of the many-to-many relationships between other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, naming-conventions, many-to-many

I'm embarrassingly enough stuck in one of my projects because I can't think of a name for this third table. My two first tables are called

```
pltest
```

and

```
pltest_foo
```

Each pltest (Ping Loss Test) can have many pltest_foos and vice versa. What to I call the third table that keeps track of the connections?

Comment: There isn't one - people have numerous ways to name the table: [table1]_[table2]_LINK/XREF/MAP... This is a dupe - the last one I saw on this was years back now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually just join the two table names with an underscore, although that would probably look odd in this case: `pltest_pltest_foo`. There's no real need to get any fancier than that, usually.

Comment: That has been my approach earlier too, but as you said it looks odd in this case. I was thinking something like `pltest_x_pltest_foo`, which on second thought doesn't really look any better...

Comment: Well, what works is more important than what looks good anyway, at least at this level. Unless you have regular users looking right at the database (and I hope you don't!) the table names only have to make sense to the programmers and DBAs actually dealing with the DB itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion `pltest_pltest_foo` would suffice.